# empty \citetitle when using chicago-authordate style

Tags: biblatex-chicago

Encountered some puzzling behavior with the `biblatex-chicago` package. When using the `authordate` option, which is one of two common use-cases of this package, the `citetitle` command produces no output.

I tried reading through the package documentation and found no mention of this behavior.

How can I tweak my document so that `citetitle` produces meaningful output? And is this the intended behavior?

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{my.bib}
  @article{my_article,
    title={Title},
    author={Smithers, Mister},
    year = {1992},
  }    
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{my.bib}
\begin{document}
    This results in a blank: \citetitle{my_article}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you use `book` instead of `article`, it works. If you use `biblatex` instead of `biblatex-chicago`, it works. I think it's a bug of `biblatex-chicago` with `article`.

Comment: The `.bbl` contains `\field{labeltitlesource}{author}` rather than `\field{labeltitlesource}{title}` when `biblatex-chicago` is used and this is the problem. If the line in the `.bbl` is corrected manually, the document compiles as expected. This should be reported to `biblatex-chicago`'s author as a bug.

Comment: good find! I didn't think to try other document classes after trying article and standalone

Comment: @Shffl It's not the document class. It's the entry type i.e. `@article`.

Comment: my mistake, read through too quickly

Comment: i've reported it to the package author

Comment: There's a note in `chicago-dates-common.cbx` which likely explains why this happens for articles but not books. I don't entirely understand it but it concludes that `we can't simply print the labeltitle for these entry types`.

Comment: If you add `\DeclareLabeltitle[article,review,suppperiodical]{%
  \field{shorttitle}
  \field{title} 
  \field{shortauthor}
  \field{author}
  \field{shorteditor}
  \field{namea}
  \field{editor}
  \field{nameb}
  \field{translator}
  \field{namec}
  \field{shortjournal}
  \field{journaltitle}}%` to your preamble it 'solves' the problem, but this will presumably break the formatting of authorless articles mentioned in the comments. If you don't have authorless articles, reviews or supplementary-journal-items, you could try it, but you'd need to triple check the output.

Comment: I think that's more than sufficient for my use case. Can you write that up as an answer so I can accept it?